# Complex date axis plotting with R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have the following data sample:

```
Device Time             Engine RPM(rpm)
10-apr-2016 19:24:59.687    1413.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:00.686    1413.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:01.691    1413.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:02.682    1215
10-apr-2016 19:25:03.699    1180.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:04.692    1052.75
10-apr-2016 19:25:05.690    1043.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:06.684    1018
10-apr-2016 19:25:07.690    1123.75
10-apr-2016 19:25:08.694    1092.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:09.699    1117
10-apr-2016 19:25:10.688    1225.5
10-apr-2016 19:25:11.691    1204.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:12.686    1166.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:13.686    1143.5
10-apr-2016 19:25:14.686    1059.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:15.686    993.75
10-apr-2016 19:25:16.691    1013.25
10-apr-2016 19:25:17.695    1252
```

How can I plot these data with R? I've seen other questions, but none is like these sample.
P.S: The date dd-mmmm-yyyy can be neglected in graph visualization.

Answer (score 2):

One can be like this:

```
> plot(x = df$Time, y = df$Engine.RPM.rpm,xlab='Time',ylab='Engine RPM(rpm)')
```

[image]
Another can be like this:

```
> barplot(height=df$Engine.RPM.rpm,names.arg=df$Time,xlab='Time',ylab='Engine RPM(rpm)')
```

[image]